# Not able to enable xp_cmdshell via Openquery() in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, dblink, openquery, xp-cmdshell

I have DB Links access from Instance 1 -> Instance 2.
I can enable/disable xp_cmdshell in Instance 1 by directly executing the SQL query. But when I try with Openquery() I cannot enable it. I have sysadmin privilege in both Instances.

I got no result for below query (Becuase of 'SELECT 1', the error is suppressed):

```
$Query = "select * from openquery(""INSTANCE2"",'SELECT 1; EXECUTE(''master..sp_configure ''''show advanced option'''', 1; RECONFIGURE; master..sp_configure ''''xp_cmdshell'''', 1; RECONFIGURE;'')               ')"        
$cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($Query,$conn)
$results = $cmd.ExecuteReader() 
$results.Close()
```

When I tried the below query :

```
$Query = "select * from openquery(""INSTANCE2"",'EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure ''show advanced option'', 1; RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE; EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure ''xp_cmdshell'', 0; RECONFIGURE;                ')"
```

I got error:

```
Exception calling "ExecuteReader" with "0" argument(s): "The metadata could not be determined because the statement 'select name,
                        convert(int, minimum) as minimum,
                        convert(int, maximum) as maximum,
                        convert' in procedure 'sp_configure' is not compatible with the statement 'select duplicate_options = name
                from sys.configurations
                where lower(name collate Latin1_Genera' in procedure 'sp_configure'."
At ...
+     $results = $cmd.ExecuteReader()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException
```

Can't I enable xp_cmdshell using openquery() ? How can I achieve the same?